# FB Prophet: OSError: Permission Denied

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to download fb prophet and keep getting the following error:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'LICENSE.md'

This is a new computer that I am in the process of downloading the python libraries I use.

I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it trying to install the package to a directory that you do not have permission to modify?